# Executing Macro in Teradata .net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, macros, teradata

I am trying to execute a macro/stored proc from Teradata to my .Net website.

My CS code looks like this -

```
 public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TdConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new TdConnectionStringBuilder();
        connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = "URL";
        connectionStringBuilder.Database = "DB";
        connectionStringBuilder.UserId = "USERNAME";
        connectionStringBuilder.Password = "PASSWORD";
        connectionStringBuilder.AuthenticationMechanism = "LDAP";

        using (TdConnection cn = new TdConnection())
        {
            cn.ConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
            cn.Open();

            TdCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "EXEC DB.TEST";


            using (TdDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                MeanTime.Text = "Value is " + reader.Read();
            }
        }

    }
```

My other attempt was

```
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC TMP_WORK_DB.SH_TEST";
string scalar = (string)cmd.executescalar();
 meantime.text = scalar;
```

My HTML side

```
 <asp:Label ID="MeanTime" runat="server" Text="MeanTime"></asp:Label>
```

The macro DB.TEST returns just one value and not a row.
The above code fails. I suspect I need to insert the value into a dataset but I have no idea about Teradata syntax

EDIT - 
Above code fails -
Visual Studio hangs when executing on the Chrome. Upon closing Chrome, it highlights CMD (code in editor) and just remains hung until force closed.

I am referring [.Net Developer Guide for Teradata](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/16.20/help/Teradata.Client.Provider~Teradata.Client.Provider_namespace.html)  and this [TD Guide page](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/16.20/help/Teradata.Client.Provider~Teradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand.html)

Comment: _"The above code fails"_ - read [ask] and explain how it fails, as well as what you have tried to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure you are using `reader.Read()` wrong.  According to your help link (https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/16.20/help/Teradata.Client.Provider~Teradata.Client.Provider.TdDataReader.html) it should be:

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    //assuming you have only one column and one row.
    //otherwise it would overwrite your Text property with the next
    //row in line
    MeanTime.Text = "Value is " + reader.GetValue(0);
}
```

This is basically the same usage and behaviour as the default DataReader: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: Getting Teradata.Client.Provider.TdException: 'External component has thrown an exception.' on var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();